# Ruby on Rails, rake db:seed or db:reset - how do you dictate which mode (development/test/production)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku

With Ruby on Rails, when you reset or re-seed the database using rake db:seed or db:reset - how do you dictate which mode (development/test/production) the operation is to be in?

I'm using Sqlite for development, and postgresql for both test and production - but with different connection arguments. I do not seem to be able to control which mode Rails runs on on my development box (I'm running in a virtual machine, Ubuntu 13.l0) nor when on Heroku.

Also, how do you dictate which mode (development/test/production) to run your app in, when running it on Heroku? The way that Heroku's document suggests, does not work (that is, putting into the Procfile a single line with
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -E $RACK_ENV
and including a .env file that has RACK_ENV=test
(for example).
?
Thank you for any help. I am really hating Ruby-on-Rails.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set environment with `RAILS_ENV` env variable, for example:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:seed
```